# Integrate WPF application into web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wpf, deployment, clickonce

Can a web application be integrated with WPF application. If there is a link in web application(ASP.NET MVC 5 in my case) which opens up the WPF application from my local machine, it should be great.

Requirement goes similar to something like gotomeeting where I click on a link(from web) and it opens up my locally installed gotomeeting.(Or launching my skype application from a link in web). In case the WPF app is not installed on local machine, it downloads the exe. In case the WPF app is updated, it updated the local app.

Checked ClickOnce on the WPF application, but somehow does not work as expected. The "launch" link in the publish.html works only with IE.

Can anyone please suggest me something to get started. If any articles or links are present, please post it here. I have gone through numerous links but did not get something which is extremely relevant.

Thanks,
Sam.

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/deploying-a-wpf-application-wpf

Answer (score 0):

One of the things about web pages are in the browser in a security sandbox.
It is intentionally difficult for them to just "reach out" onto your machine and run some exe or other.

If your machine already has an application associated with a particular file extension then you can get it to do it's default action when such a file is delivered.
Like open a mail object in outlook.

To run an exe from a web app you'd have to rely on a custom file extension and deliver a file that the machine "knows" means run wpf application xyz.
Clickonce is likely to be problematic if you're passing objects in because it installs to the user's appdata. You can't predict where it will be.
Just running one works from a url, but to start up with an object out a page sounds like it could be problematic.  I never tried it though.

You could conceivably make your wpf app an xbap. http://www.xbap.org/  That's wpf in a browser.
Or there is of course still Silverlight. I think that still goes out of support in 3 years and you're probably now limited to IE as well.